# Can i add an URL while creating a Calendar with Google API?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

In the instruction manual of Google API Calendar i found how to create a Calendar and get the ID. But now i want also in the same code to add an URL that links to my own website and get all the events of my ics file.

```
$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary('calendarSummary');
$calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

echo $createdCalendar->getId();
```

So i have different URL's and each URL needs to be linked to a certain Calendar. By example:

> I create calendarFamily and that needs to be linked with
>   https://myownwebsite.com/getAgenda/123456Family/987654  and then i
>   need to create a calendarFootball that needs to be linked to
>   https://myownwebsite.com/getAgenda/123456Football/987654

But everything needs to be generated in code, because when i add a new calendar, it needs ot automatically create a Google Calendar and get its events from a generated url.

Can someone help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add this url?  On your own website your going to have to generate a new webpage i would suspect and have this new web page include the code needed to download the events from Google calendar.

Comment: If you go to a Calendar in Google you can refer to an URL to get the events from that URL in ics. But i manage all the calendars from my users, so i want to let my application (when i create a calendar) immediately to add this URL, so my users don't have to do this.

Comment: check [events.import](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/import)

Comment: That is to import events. But i want immidiatly subscribe to an external calendar. Manually you can do it like this (sorry for the Dutch language) https://imgur.com/a/VbH8zvs but i want to do it with an api call. Kind regards

Comment: I suspect that what you want to do is  not possible. this is the closest that i am aware of.

Comment: So dissapointing...